# How do i create cordova electron build with `nsis-web` package?

Tags: windows, cordova, electron, nsis

I am trying to create a cordova electron build with package type `nsis-web` but i am unable to pass other options to the build type

nsis-web is supported by cordova electron according to this chart https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/electron/index.html#adding-a-package

my `build.json`

```
{
    "electron": {
        "windows": {
            "package": [
                "nsis-web",
                {
                    "nsis-web": {
                        "appPackageUrl": "https://someurl.tld/apps/win/web"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "arch": [
                "x64"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the following error

```
  • electron-builder  version=22.7.0 os=19.5.0
  • writing effective config  file=platforms/electron/build/builder-effective-config.yaml
  • installing production dependencies  platform=win32 arch=x64 appDir=/platforms/electron/www
Unknown target: nsisweb
```

If i dont pass the extra parameter `appPackageUrl` it gives following error

```
  • electron-builder  version=22.7.0 os=19.5.0
  • writing effective config  file=platforms/electron/build/builder-effective-config.yaml
  • installing production dependencies  platform=win32 arch=x64 appDir=platforms/electron/www
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=9.0.0 appOutDir=platforms/electron/build/win-unpacked
  • building        target=nsis-web file=platforms/electron/build/nsis-web/setup.exe archs=x64 oneClick=true perMachine=false
  • building embedded block map  file=platforms/electron/build/nsis-web/<package-name>-3.3.5-x64.nsis.7z
Cannot compute app package download URL
```

How do i create a `nsis-web` package with cordova electron?

I am using the nightly build of `cordova-electron` package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was confirmed to be a missing item in the cordova-electron package, I was able to connect with the developers and a fix is being put in place which will be available in `cordova-electron@2.0.0` release

[PR link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-electron/compare/master...erisu:fix/format-root-target-keys)